# Proper way to get reference to row in 2D array

Tags: c

I've tried several times to find an answer to this question but I think I'm wording my search poorly, but I'm having a hard time getting my head around this. Too much time away from C I guess.

I have a compile time declared 2D buffer:

```
uint8_t buffers[NUM_BUFS][SIZE_BUF];
```

This should be `NUM_BUFS` equal in size to `SIZE_BUF` correct? I visualize this as `NUM_BUFS` rows, with `SIZE_BUF` columns.

Now I want to do two things:

1. Get a reference to a single row to feed a function
2. Get a reference to a single element in a row, from the row reference.

Here is what I have tried:

From a pointer standpoint:

```
uint8_t* row = *(buffers + SIZE_BUF*rowIDX);

uint8_t element = *(row + elementIDX);
```

This compiles fine and works, but is cumbersome.

From a array access standpoint:

```
uint8_t* row = &buffers[rowIDX];

uint8_t element = row[elementIDX];
```

This gives me a compiler warning when trying to pass a row to a function which will access its elements: `passing argument 1 of 'someFunc' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`

And an info statement of: `expected 'uint8_t *' but argument is of type 'uint8_t (*)[515]'`

Where `someFunc` is declared as:
    void someFunc(uint8_t* row, uint16_t len);

I would appreciate some help on what the standard way of doing this is, and if there is one which has the readability of array brackets.

Comment: Please use 4 spaces to indent your code. This enables highlighting, and makes your code much more readable.

Comment: `uint8_t* row = *(buffers + SIZE_BUF*rowIDX);` This isn't just cumbersome; its *wrong*. `buffers` in this expression evaluates as `uint8_t (*)[SIZE_BUF]`. There should be no `SIZE_BUF` in your addition; it should be simply `*(buffers + rowIDX)`, or using the subscript operator, `buffers[rowIDX]`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I agree. I had that originally and thought I was getting the wrong memory location but it turns out that was for another reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
void someFunc(uint8_t *ptr)
{
}
```

with this:

```
uint8_t buffers[NUM_BUFS][SIZE_BUF];
uint8_t* row = buffers[rowIDX];
uint8_t element = row[elementIDX];
someFunc(row);
```

Comment: I hate when I overlook the obvious.

Comment: @Jared Heh, don't we all.

Answer (score 0):

For rows, you simply write `uint8_t * row = buffers[rowIDX];`

Then you simply access an element in `row` like this: `row[colIDX]`

Note that this would not work as is for a column because C use row-major order for 2D arrays: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

For columns, you must write `uint8_t * col= &buffers[0][colIDX];`

Then you access an element in `col` like this: `col[rowIDX * SIZE_BUF]`

For example:

```
#include "stdio.h"


#define NUM_BUFS 10
#define SIZE_BUF 20

uint8_t buffers[NUM_BUFS][SIZE_BUF];

void PrintRow(uint8_t * row) {
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<SIZE_BUF; ++i) printf("%lu\n", row[i]);
}

void PrintCol(uint8_t * col) {
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<NUM_BUFS; ++i) printf("%lu\n", col[i*SIZE_BUF]);
}

int main() {

    for (uint8_t i=0; i<NUM_BUFS; ++i) for (uint8_t j=0; j<SIZE_BUF; ++j) buffers[i][j] = i*j;

    uint8_t rowIDX = 3;

    printf("Row:\n");
    uint8_t * row = buffers[rowIDX];
    PrintRow(row);

    uint8_t colIDX = 3;
    printf("Col:\n");
    uint8_t * col = &buffers[0][colIDX];
    PrintCol(col);
}
```